# Periods in batch file variables

Tags: variables, batch-file, lame

I'm making a batch file for LAME mp3 encoding on Windows 7 64 bit.  I used a bit of code I got from this site as the basis, then tried to add a little bit so I could tell it to encode with the artist and album name.  I ripped some CDs so they would end up nesting like `xxx\artist\album\songs.wav`. Here's the full code:

```
for %%q in (.) do set Album=%%~nq
for %%x in (..) do set Artist=%%~nx
for %%i in (*.wav) do "D:\Program Files\lame\lame.exe" -V1 --
vbr-old --tl "%Album%" --ta "%Artist%" "%%i" "%%~ni.mp3"
```

To use it I copy the batch file into the album folder among the songs.  It works fine for some albums, but when I tried to use it for an album by "M.I.A" it records the artist as "M.I".  Is there some problem with the periods? If there is, why does it let one through but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"M.I.A" is seen as a filename "M.I" with an extension ".A'

Try replacing `~nq` with `~nxq`  and `~nx` with `~nxx`

`%%~nxq` means `name and extension of %%q` but `%%~nq` means `name only of %%q`

Comment: That works perfect.  I didn't even think about it like a file extension, because, y'know, it's a folder.  Thanks!